# How to ignore the 'not covered by tests' warning?

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube version 6.4. I am not writing any test cases, when I check SonarQube, it shows quality gate failed. The error message is:

> not covered by tests.

Is it possible to avoid or ignore the same for all the projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the default quality gate settings. Go to `Quality Gates`, select the default Quality Gate and delete the code coverage metrics.