# SonarQube ignoring the @SuppressWarnings("all") command

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a simple POJO class that has a `isValid` method:

```
public class MyClass{
    ...

    @ValidationMethod(message = "age must be ...")
    @JsonIgnore
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public boolean isValid() {
       return age > 10;
    }
}
```

I like the SonarQube to ignore this method when it checks the project.

I don't like to remove all the test coverage checks in the project, but not to check this specific line.

So I added the `@SuppressWarnings("all")`  on top of the method, as suggested [here](https://docs.codescan.io/hc/en-us/articles/360012109711-Ignoring-violations) and [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/its/plugin/projects/suppress-warnings/src/main/java/SuppressWarningsAtMethodLevel.java). I also try to use the `//NOSONAR` at the end of the line:

```
 public boolean isValid() {
    return age > 10;//NOSONAR
}
```

Yet, in both cases, the SonarQube ignores the suppress requests and gives an error about

> "Not Covered by tests"

:

What are we missing here? Are there more settings to do in the SonarQube itself? Are we doing it wrong?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45365779/how-to-ignore-the-not-covered-by-tests-warning

Comment: @user7294900 I don't like to remove all the test coverage checks in the project, but not to check this specific line. I'll update my question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135939/how-to-make-sonar-ignore-some-classes-for-codecoverage-metric/27133765

Answer (score 0):

So, following the comment of user7294900 I was able to partially success by telling sonar to completely ignore the class.

This was not our initial requirement - we wanted to just ignore the method.

We did it by adding the following `<sonar.exclusions>` to the `pom.xml` in the `<properties>` section, so the final result looks something like that:

```
 <properties>     
    <mainClass>com.example.MyApplication</mainClass>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/MyClass.java</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```